# Wildfly Swarm deployment issue - Failed to resolve artifact 'xalan:serializer:2.7.1.jbossorg-2'

Tags: gradle, wildfly, swarm

Using gradle script:

```
buildscript {
    version = System.getProperty('swarmVersion') ?: '2017.1.1'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.0.RC2"
        classpath "org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:$version"
    }
}

apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
apply plugin: 'wildfly-swarm'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'test.Main'

swarm {
    properties {
        swarm.http.port = 8080
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.repository.redhat.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.repository.redhat.com/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/'
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.wildfly.swarm:bom-all:$version"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.wildfly.swarm:jaxrs"
}
```

test.Main

```
  package test;

import test.resources.TestResource;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm;
import org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.JAXRSArchive;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    Swarm swarm = new Swarm();
    JAXRSArchive deployment = ShrinkWrap.create(JAXRSArchive.class);
    deployment.addClass(TestResource.class);
    deployment.addAllDependencies();
    swarm.start();
    swarm.deploy(deployment);
  }
}
```

Im getting this error while starting jar:

```
2017-01-24 12:00:35,363 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."8cf83a03-d940-4e8b-b223-f9a9e00976ce.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."8cf83a03-d940-4e8b-b223-f9a9e00976ce.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "8cf83a03-d940-4e8b-b223-f9a9e00976ce.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYUT0049: Error loading SCI from module: javax.servlet.jstl.api:main
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:118)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from modules/org/apache/xalan/main/module.xml
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:228)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.ClasspathModuleFinder.findModule(ClasspathModuleFinder.java:80)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.findModule(ModuleLoader.java:439)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:342)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:289)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1079)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1449)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1477)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:225)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:109)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Failed to resolve artifact 'xalan:serializer:2.7.1.jbossorg-2' (position: END_TAG seen ...esources>\n    <artifact name="xalan:serializer:2.7.1.jbossorg-2"/>... @5:57) 
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseArtifact(ModuleXmlParser.java:838)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseResources(ModuleXmlParser.java:739)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleContents(ModuleXmlParser.java:535)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseDocument(ModuleXmlParser.java:340)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:226)
        ... 15 more

2017-01-24 12:00:35,371 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (main) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: (("deployment" => "8cf83a03-d940-4e8b-b223-f9a9e00976ce.war")) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"8cf83a03-d940-4e8b-b223-f9a9e00976ce.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"8cf83a03-d940-4e8b-b223-f9a9e00976ce.war\".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"8cf83a03-d940-4e8b-b223-f9a9e00976ce.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYUT0049: Error loading SCI from module: javax.servlet.jstl.api:main
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from modules/org/apache/xalan/main/module.xml
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Failed to resolve artifact 'xalan:serializer:2.7.1.jbossorg-2' (position: END_TAG seen ...esources>\\n    <artifact name=\"xalan:serializer:2.7.1.jbossorg-2\"/>... @5:57) "},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"8cf83a03-d940-4e8b-b223-f9a9e00976ce.war\".INSTALL"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
2017-01-24 12:00:35,374 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "8cf83a03-d940-4e8b-b223-f9a9e00976ce.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"8cf83a03-d940-4e8b-b223-f9a9e00976ce.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"8cf83a03-d940-4e8b-b223-f9a9e00976ce.war\".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"8cf83a03-d940-4e8b-b223-f9a9e00976ce.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYUT0049: Error loading SCI from module: javax.servlet.jstl.api:main
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from modules/org/apache/xalan/main/module.xml
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Failed to resolve artifact 'xalan:serializer:2.7.1.jbossorg-2' (position: END_TAG seen ...esources>\\n    <artifact name=\"xalan:serializer:2.7.1.jbossorg-2\"/>... @5:57) "},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"8cf83a03-d940-4e8b-b223-f9a9e00976ce.war\".INSTALL"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with the gradle plugin for Wildfly Swarm, such as

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SWARM-542 and

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SWARM-826

And [this comment](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wildfly-swarm/qjqk3BKQM78) doesn't make me confident that they are going to be fixed any time soon.

To this end, for the time being my approach is simply to assume that the only way to reliably build a Swarm application with Gradle is to start by building a hollow Swarm uberjar using Maven, and then integrate the resulting Wildfly jar using Gradle or (as I've done), in Docker.

You miss out on the automatic fraction detection (which didn't seem to work for me in gradle anyway) but on the other hand you do get faster build times if you're not building the entire uberjar for every build. And of course since Maven is apparently a first-class citizen for Red Hat, you're decoupling yourself from depending on a build tool that isn't vendor supported.

More information about hollow uberjars:

https://wildfly-swarm.gitbooks.io/wildfly-swarm-users-guide/content/getting-started/tooling/maven-plugin.html

To deploy your application with the uberjar you can just add the WAR to the commandline:

```
java -jar my-hollow-swarm.jar my-application.war
```

As an aside, you can also pass in configuration and other details:

```
java -jar my-hollow-swarm.jar my-application.war -c /etc/config.xml
java -jar my-hollow-swarm.jar my-application.war --help
```

Comment: after having so many troubles and being simply ignored by core devs, I came across your answer and I think it is an excellent solution. however I can't work it out what the best way for using a custom main with this solution is. can it be put in the hollow uberjar generator or shall it be in a separate (possibly Gradle) module?

Comment: also it would be nice to know how do you package the dependencies of the Gradle output so that it can be run by hollow uberjar with min problems.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out workaround if i add package to deployment then swarm is able to deploy it normally. Below is solution which worked for me.

```
Swarm swarm = new Swarm();
JAXRSArchive deployment = ShrinkWrap.create(JAXRSArchive.class);
deployment.addPackage("test");
deployment.addAllDependencies();
swarm.start();
swarm.deploy(deployment);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the JBoss Nexus repository in your Maven settings.

See also:

- [Maven Getting Started - Users Guide on JBoss.org](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users) (Applies even if you build with Gradle! See reasons below.)

An example:

- https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/8f7e87bf282877a7a5554035abb709cc9813fec2/settings-example.xml

The reason is that while the WildFly Swarm and the WildFly provisioning tool download the artifacts correctly, some of them are only available on JBoss Nexus and Maven will track this in the metadata of your local cache.

When you will run a different process - like your own application - without enabling this repository, the Eclipse Aether library which is being used will (as expected) respect this metadata and ignore any artifacts which has not been sourced by any currently enabled repository.